# What does the residue of masking and duct tape smell like?

Tags: tape

I laid some vinyl and went around the perimieter of my whole room with yellow masking tape and duct tape.  Under the vinyl there are floorboards which have laminate the back of which seem to gas noticeable formaldehyde. I know there was also some damp under the floorboards which is no longer getting moisture.

Anyway today I removed the duct tape and masking tape and it has expected a formaldehyde type green smell like if that makes any sense.  I’m trying to figure out if the smell was is from damp, laminate or duct tape or masking tape residue.

Can you tell me what the residue of the two tapes smell like? I’m working on Cleaning up the residue but it doesn’t seem like an easy task.  Meantime I want to know what this smell is as I’d like to get rid of it and know where to focus my efforts.

Thanks

Comment: you are asking a silly question ... you have the tape there ... why don't you smell it?

Comment: @jsotola I thought there’s no such thing as a silly question.  I took the two up after years and tbh I cannot discern what the smell is. Thought people here with more experience might know.

Comment: I sincerely doubt the tape is the cause. Suggest you air the place for a few days and see (smell) how it goes.

Comment: yes, questions can be silly when the asker does not think about what they are asking .... you said that you peeled off the tape, which means that you are holding it in your hand ... take the tape outside and smell it ... it is simple as that ... if you smell something different inside the house, then the smell is not from the tape

Comment: I have been in morgues and watched embalming... Are you sure you know what formaldehyde smells like?! Trust me, formaldehyde does not have a green smell.  Every Manufacturer uses different glue on their tape, there is no way we know what you are Smelling.

Comment: I have never noticed a strong odor from masking tape.  formaldehide smell is usually rotting MDF or particle board.